# API Gateway and Lambda Function: first approach

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am very new to the API Gateway and AWS Lambda and I am trying to use them in a scenario with the following elements:

- a VPC with a private and a public subnet
- an AMI EC2 (Free Tier) with Lamp Installed
- A simple index.html page with some text (something saying "This is a test page")

What I would like to do is to be able to punch http://myprivateIp/myexample/index.hml through the use of the API gateway and Lambda as it seems to be suggested in the AWS documentation. I have, then, re-used the basic Hello World lambda example (one of the AWS blueprints) for my first lambda function and included the VPC details (with the private subnet too) as requested in the wizard. I have also created a sample API with one resource (myexample, in this case) and the Get method with the Lambda Function Integration Type and the Hello World function. As per the documentation, I have created the correct permissions (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/create-lambda-roles.html). I have tested the GET method from my API and it correctly returns the response "Hello World" as per the AWS pre-existing blueprint. I know this might sound like a very naive question, but I am not sure whether I have really proven that I can hit my VPC? I would like to be able to return the sample text from my index.html page, for example, Is that possible? Have I misunderstood the purpose of AWS lambda in this particular scenario?

Thank you for your help,

**EDIT:**

So, I have put together the following in Node JS 4.3:

```
'use strict';
console.log('We are about to send a Get Request');

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  var http = require("http")
  var request = http.get("http://domain/example/index.html")
  console.log('"This is my request":"' + request + '"');
  callback(null, "The URL is succesfully retrieved")
};
```

The test runs successfully, am I right in saying that it does prove that I can hit a page running on a VPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - you can make an HTTP request to an endpoint in your VPC via a Lambda function as long as your Lambda function is configured to run inside the same VPC.

Thus, you can use API Gateway to call Lambda and proxy a response back from an HTTP endpoint within a VPC.

API Gateway cannot call HTTP endpoints in a VPC directly, so your current approach using Lambda is the recommended one.

Comment: thanks for this, much appreciated. Just wanted to find out whether I was actually going towards the right direction and yes the test seems to work and I can hit that page within the VPC. I guess I can do a similar thing with a REST endpoint, instead of a HTTP resource. Is that correct?

Comment: This approach will work but it is not scalable because whenever lambda need to access any resource in VPC, it requires ENI (elastic network interface) and sufficient IP address and to ensure this stuff could be tricky. It would recommend to take a brief look for all concerns on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html before to move in this direction.

Comment: @paranza : How was your experience with this approach ?

Answer (score -2):

You can connect your EC2 with private IP within your Lambda function. That means you can hit your VPC from your Lambda function.

Comment: This does not answer user issue

Comment: @Ka Hou leong, thanks for your input. When setting up the lambda function, under Configurations -> Advanced Settings, I am allowed to connect to the VPC of choice (which I have done). On that VPC, I have Lamp running (the only instance at the moment) with Apache and one sample web page. Is that what you mean? Is my test already proving that I can successfully connect to the EC2 instance? I am struggling to see whether with Lambda I can simply perhaps get the header of that index.html page? Thank you